# Qlik Sense error, Invalid Path while using load from resident table

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have loaded a table as follows by this SQL Query in QlikSense data load editor,

```
[RESOURCE_ALLOCATION]:
select t.rec_id as RESOURCE_ALLOC_TASKID,
t.name as RESOURCE_ALLOC_TASKNAME,
t.actual_starttime as RESOURCE_ALLOC_STARTTIME,
t.actual_endtime as RESOURCE_ALLOC_ENDTIME,
extract(year from t.actual_starttime) as RESOURCE_ALLOC_YEAR,
(t.actual_endtime - t.actual_starttime) as RESOURCE_ALLOC_DAYS,
t.resource_id as RESOURCE_ALLOC_ERSOURCEID,
r.name as RESOURCE_ALLOC_ERSOURCENAME
from public.dsh_project_tasks t, public.dsh_resources r
where t.resource_id = r.rec_id and extract(year from t.actual_starttime) = extract (year from t.actual_endtime);
```

Then I am tring to load another table by selecting from the last loaded table [RESOURCE_ALLOCATION] by another Query just after the one above in the load data editor , as follows

```
[Resource_Utilization]:
load rr.RESOURCE_ALLOC_ERSOURCENAME as busy_resourcename,
          rr.RESOURCE_ALLOC_YEAR as busy_resourceyear,
          Sum(rr.RESOURCE_ALLOC_DAYS) as busy_resourceDays,
          if(Sum(rr.RESOURCE_ALLOC_DAYS) < 368, 'busy', 'free')as BUSY_RESOURCESTATUS
from RESOURCE_ALLOCATION rr
group by rr.RESOURCE_ALLOC_ERSOURCENAME, rr.RESOURCE_ALLOC_YEAR;




[Resource_Utilization]:
load rr.RESOURCE_ALLOC_ERSOURCENAME as busy_resourcename,
rr.RESOURCE_ALLOC_YEAR as busy_resourceyear,
(365 - Sum(rr.RESOURCE_ALLOC_DAYS)) as busy_resourceDays,
if((365 - Sum(rr.RESOURCE_ALLOC_DAYS)) < 366, 'free', 'busy') as BUSY_RESOURCESTATUS
from resource_allocation rr
group by rr.RESOURCE_ALLOC_ERSOURCENAME, rr.RESOURCE_ALLOC_YEAR;
```

But I have  an error in load data , saying

The following error occurred:
Invalid Path
The error occurred here:

```
[Resource_Utilization]:
load rr.RESOURCE_ALLOC_ERSOURCENAME as busy_resourcename,
rr.RESOURCE_ALLOC_YEAR as busy_resourceyear,
Sum(rr.RESOURCE_ALLOC_DAYS) as busy_resourceDays,
if(Sum(rr.RESOURCE_ALLOC_DAYS) < 368, 'busy', 'free')as BUSY_RESOURCESTATUS 
from RESOURCE_ALLOCATION rr group by rr.RESOURCE_ALLOC_ERSOURCENAME, rr.RESOURCE_ALLOC_YEAR
```

Please help, why Do I get this error although same Query is selecting data well in DB console??

Answer (score 2):

`[Resource_Utilization]:
load rr.RESOURCE_ALLOC_ERSOURCENAME as busy_resourcename,
          rr.RESOURCE_ALLOC_YEAR as busy_resourceyear,
          Sum(rr.RESOURCE_ALLOC_DAYS) as busy_resourceDays,
          if(Sum(rr.RESOURCE_ALLOC_DAYS) < 368, 'busy', 'free')as BUSY_RESOURCESTATUS
from RESOURCE_ALLOCATION rr
group by rr.RESOURCE_ALLOC_ERSOURCENAME, rr.RESOURCE_ALLOC_YEAR;`

The SQL Syntax only works when the query is being passed to an SQL Server. When using the resulting tables you need to use the native Qlik Sense scripting language syntax. It's quite similar what you need to make your script work is this;

```
[Resource_Utilization]:
load RESOURCE_ALLOC_ERSOURCENAME as busy_resourcename,
      RESOURCE_ALLOC_YEAR as busy_resourceyear,
      Sum(RESOURCE_ALLOC_DAYS) as busy_resourceDays,
      if(Sum(RESOURCE_ALLOC_DAYS) < 368, 'busy', 'free') as BUSY_RESOURCESTATUS
resident RESOURCE_ALLOCATION
      group by RESOURCE_ALLOC_ERSOURCENAME, RESOURCE_ALLOC_YEAR;
```

The key change being changing the FROM to RESIDENT so the Sense knows to look inside it's own results tables not some external source for the table you reference. The rr. abbbreviations will cause it fail as Sense can only reference one table per script request.